# What type do I need to create to pass a json key value pair back to angular from .Net

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, .net-core, key-value

I'm trying to use a Angular [keyvaluepair](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) and I want to pass this below to my angular type attorneys: { [key: number]: string };

> {2: 'foo', 1: 'bar'};

back to my UI from the controller.

Here is my controller:

```
    [HttpGet("check/{matter}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SearchMatter(string matter)
    {
        var exists =  await _cmpRepo.CheckMatter(matter);

        if (!exists)
            return BadRequest("error");

        var claims = await _autoRepo.GetClaimsByMatter(matter);

        var attorneys = await _autoRepo.GetAttorneys();

        return Ok(new ClaimInfo { Names = claims, Attorneys = attorneys });
    }
```

Here is ClaimInfo.cs

```
public class ClaimInfo
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Names { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>> Attorneys { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is [working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-acrncn?file=src/app/app.component.ts) 
.ts

```
 keyVal = {
    1: "foo",
    2: "chanaka",
  };
```

.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of keyVal | keyvalue">
      {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
</div>
```

Comment: yes I can see this from the Angular example, but what I need to know is how to get the keyVal {} from c#. Currently I can serialize a dict but that leaves me with a json object (which is what I need) inside a string. So now I have to remove the outer parentheses.

Comment: I got it. JSON.parse(string)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to remove the ""
var obj - JSON.parse(string)

Comment: @karel still a **low quality** self-`answer`.